# How to change tick-marks for y-axis in base histogram?

Tags: r, histogram, yaxis

I would like to change my Y axis of these histograms to start at 20 and end at 180 AND making it so there is always 20 between each number (20, 40, 80, ...). How should I do it?

I read about yaxis command, but I just dont know how to make it work as I am a total noob in coding (no education in that area).

**This is the graph I am working on:**

[image]

**And this is the code I have:**

```
orientation$head_linear <- ifelse(orientation$head > 180, 360 - orientation$head, orientation$head) 
orientation$body_linear <- ifelse(orientation$body > 180, 360 - orientation$body, orientation$body)

par(mfrow = c(2,1)) 
hist(orientation$head_linear, main = NULL, ylim=c(20,180), ylab = NULL, xlab = NULL) 
hist(orientation$body_linear, main = NULL, ylim=c(20, 180), ylab = NULL, xlab = " Odchylka od vletového otvoru ")
```

I have set the limit of Y axis with ylim code, but it doesnt seem to work (I have succesfully  used it before in different work).

Comment: Hi, please provide some toy data next time, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean the `xaxt=` argument whith which you can omit the y-axis. If you use it, you may create a custom `axis` afterwards. Use a `seq(from=0, to=360, by=20)` for it's `at=` argument.

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 1)) 

hist(orientation$head_linear, main=NULL, yaxt='n', ylab=NULL, xlab=NULL) 
axis(side=2, at=seq(from=0, to=360, by=20))

hist(orientation$body_linear, main=NULL, yaxt='n', ylab=NULL, xlab=" Odchylka od vletového otvoru ")
axis(2, seq(0, 360, 20))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 500
orientation <- data.frame(
  head_linear=sample(360, n, replace=TRUE),
  body_linear=sample(360, n, replace=TRUE)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I also changed my x axis the same way. I hope my prof likes it :)